# Optimising Box-Cox lambda analytically

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, calculus, boxcox-transformation

I'm taking a university course in statistics where the Box-Cox transform is being discussed. As I understand it, we assume that there is some $\lambda$ that makes the sample normally distributed after applying the Box-Cox transform. To find said $\lambda$, we maximise the log likelihood of the sample, where the likelihood is a Gaussian distribution evaluated in the transformed data:

[image: argmax likelihood]

For clarity: $x^{(\lambda)}$ is $\textrm{BoxCox}(x,\lambda)$ (If needed, I can convert this image from the course slides to TeX, but I don't see the use for that.) Supposedly, to maximise the expression in grey (a simplification of the likelihood), we just evaluate it for various values of $\lambda$ and empirically select the best one.

Yet, can't we solve this analytically? Why don't we just differentiate the expression to $\lambda$ and set that to $0$? Sure, that nested $\overline{x^{(\lambda)}}$ is going to require some nasty applications of the chain rule, but it should be perfectly feasible...

Comment: One problem I have seen is that the sum is inside the log function. That complicates the issue.

Comment: Also there is no way to isolate $\lambda$ even after differentiation

Comment: You have been misled, because it is never the case that there exists a $\lambda$ that makes your data Normally distributed. The best you can hope for by varying a single scalar parameter is to achieve a scalar objective, such as making the distribution *symmetric* in some sense. Yes, there even exists software to maximize the likelihood where $\lambda$ has been added to the parameters. IMHO that's rather against the exploratory spirit of Box-Cox transformations, and the results definitely must be taken with a grain of salt, but it is a useful approach. There's no closed form solution, though.

Comment: @whuber Well yes, that's why we *assume* and not *know*. The case $\lambda = 0$ should be normally distributed if the sample came from a lognormal distribution, though.

Comment: @onyambu You make a good point: the result of differentiating is likely an implicit equation of $\lambda$ that can't be made explicit. The question then is: is it better, in one way or another, to apply a numerical maximiser to the log likelihood, or to apply a numerical rootfinder to that implicit equation?

Comment: Even when the sample comes from a lognormal distribution, its logarithms will not be Normally distributed.  They cannot possibly be, because the sample has a *discrete* distribution.  It's important to distinguish properties of the data from properties of the model you invoke to help analyze those data.

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).